# C++ Why I make new struct and get error ? (Double linked list circular)

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list, runtime-error

First, I make double linked list circular like this :

1 3 9 11 13

After that, I want to insert 99 after 3. So I must make a variable struct like this :

```
node *baru;
baru = new node;
```

BUT the fact Stop there.
Here is my full code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int item;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
};
int main()
{
    node* list = new node;

    list->item = 1;
    list->next->item = 3;
    list->next->next->item = 9;
    list->next->next->next->item = 11;
    list->next->next->next->next->item = 13;
    list->next->next->next->next->next = list;
    list->prev = list->next->next->next->next;
    list->next->prev = list;
    list->next->next->prev = list->next;
    list->next->next->next->prev = list->next->next;
    list->next->next->next->next->prev = list->next->next->next;
    node *bantu = list;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cout << bantu->item << endl;
        bantu = bantu->next;
    }

    cout << endl;

    bantu = list;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cout << bantu->item << endl;
        bantu = bantu->prev;
    }

    node *baru;
    baru = new node;

    cout << "go !" << endl;

    baru->item = 99;

    baru->next = list->next->next;
    baru->prev = list->next;
    list->next->next = baru;
    list->next->next->next->prev = baru;

    cout << endl;
    bantu = list;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cout << bantu->item << endl;
        bantu = bantu->next;
    }

    cout << endl;
    bantu = list;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cout << bantu->item << endl;
        bantu = bantu->prev;
    }
    cout << "SELESAI" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

if successful, the program definitely will output the "go". But in this case, the program does not output the "go". This means that there is an error when creating a new struct. But why is the error?

sorry bad english :D
thanks you

Comment: Strongly recommend investing some time in an `insert` function

Comment: `list->next` is uninitialized which is undefined behavior. There is no `node` where it points to.

Answer (score 1):

The `node* next;` pointer is never initialized and is there for not pointing towards any instance of a node. Trying to set a variable inside an non-existing object doesn't make sense and will throw an error. In order to make it work you will have to set `next` to point to a node *before* you try to assign `next->item` a value.

As someone already mentioned you really should consider to implement an insert function. If you want to insert into the last node (which you seem to want according to your code) something like this should work:

```
void insert(node* root, int value)
{
    node* temp = root;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = new node(value);
    temp->next->prev = temp;
}
```

You should also change your node struct to:

```
struct node
{
    node(int item)
    {
        this->item = item;
    }
    int item;
    node *next = nullptr;
    node *prev = nullptr;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
node *next;
```

declares `next` to be a pointer to a `node`. To abuse an old quote, "Pointers gonna point." but it doesn't point to anything useful without help.

```
node* list = new node;
```

makes a `node` pointer named `list` and points it at a brand-new `node`. No additional `node`s are created so `list`'s `next` has nowhere to point. That means

```
list->next->item = 3;
```

wanders into [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) trying to access `list->next` to get the `item`.

The solution is to make an `insert` function to create a new `node` and perform the linking.

```
node * insertAfter(node * top, int value)
{
    node * temp = new node;
    temp->item = value;
    temp->next = nullptr; // so we know there is nothing next. 
                          // But what if there is something next? Hmmm....
    temp->prev = top;     // point back at top
    top->next = temp;     // point at temp, but what if next already pointed at something?
                          // Wowzers! This is harder than it looks!
    return temp; // return the new node so caller can do something with it if they want
}
```